# -Wait timeout? -Wait minimized?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I am writing a simple script that involves starting another process and waiting for it to finish. What I have now is working, mostly. One problem I seem to have is the Powershell window seems to time out if the other process runs for a long time. I would also like to have the Powershell wait minimized while the other process runs.

```
<#
grab files from network for use
#>

function Show-Menu {
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'Select License'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "**************** $Title ****************"

    Write-Host "1: Press '1' option 1"
    Write-Host "2: Press '2' option 2"
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to Quit." 
}


Show-Menu -Title 'Select License'
$selection = Read-Host "Which License do you need?"
switch ($selection) {
    '1' { Start-Process -FilePath "some filepath" -ArgumentList 'some arguments'-Wait -WindowStyle Maximized -WorkingDirectory "program working directory" }
    '2' { Start-Process -FilePath "some filepath" -ArgumentList 'different arguments'-Wait -WindowStyle Maximized -WorkingDirectory "program working directory" }
    'q' { return }

    Default {Show-Menu}
}

<#
send files to network
#>
```

This is the code minus the project specific info. It works, if the Start-Process target only runs for a few minutes, if longer it times out. I would like to the command line window to -Wait minimized if possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "times out"?

Comment: If the Start-Process target runs more than an hour or so, the “send files to network” section doesn’t fire.